# JS Replacing part of a version number within a file

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, version

I need to replace the version number in a file via JS and I'm having trouble targeting only the specific part that I need. I've read the contents of the file into a variable and will overwrite the entire file with the modified content. The file looks like this (standard wordpress style.css):

```
/******************************************************************
Theme Name: Starter Theme
Theme URI: 
Description: Custom Wordpress starter theme
Author: 
Author URI:
Version: 1.0.0
Tags: fluid-layout, responsive-layout, translation-ready

License: WTFPL
License URI: http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.sticky {}          /* DO NOT EDIT THIS */
.gallery-caption {} /* THESE ARE USELESS */
.bypostauthor {}    /* THEY ARE ONLY TO KEEP THEME CHECK HAPPY */
```

And the part in question is this `Version: 1.0.0`

There's a few nuances that seem to make this difficult. **I only need to change the third number** (0), as the first two (1.0) are reserved for manual editing and need to be kept the way they are (**so I cannot just replace the whole string or line**). I've been trying to extract only the last number via substring and/or regex but can't seem to figure out how to do that properly (as the content around it isn't static, plus the version string ends with a newline). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newVersion = 3;
content = content.replace(/^Version: \d+\.\d+\.\d+$/mg, function(match, index) {
    return match.replace(/\.\d+$/, '.' + newVersion);
});
```

Comment: It seems to lose the dot before the last number, but other than that this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: yeah, forgot about the dot :) now is ok

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate through each line using readline / a for loop depending upon browser/nodejs and and look for string version, change the number accordingly.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing, but I'm having trouble targeting only the last number within the version string and replacing that specifically.

Comment: You could take the whole line of version as string and split them by . Str.split('.'). Replace the last element by the desired number and join again. No regex trouble that way.